# How to get Google Tag Manager Event Tracking to send to Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, data-layers

My website has a tel: link in the header, and I want to see in Google Analytics when this link is clicked, and on what page. I've decided to do this using Event Tracking in Google Tag Manager. So I made a tag, [with the following configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJmrA.png)

[And this is my Trigger configuration.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hatX.png)

[This is the HTML that this is referencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnGHJ.png), (note that I also tried to add an `onclick` attribute, which was meant to push Event data directly to analytics. This didn't work.)

[This is the variable configuration used in this tag.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwyTh.png)

[This is proof it fires in the GTM debug pane.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKBCk.png)

[And this is the summary coming in when you click on the item withing the pane.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI0J0.png)

In Analytics, [this is what I see in the Real-time events tracking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8OxP.png)

And this is what I see under [the events overview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPTN8.png)

So the tag is firing correctly, but the information is not going over to Analytics. I can find no resource on the internet that addresses this issue. Has anyone successfully pushed Google Tag Manager event tracking into Google Analytics? If so, what did you do to make it work, and what am I not doing/doing wrong that is preventing me from the result?

The end goal is I want to track the page where the click happened in Google Analytics' Events Overview, and also in the Goals section.

Comment: probably it may be due to your tag firing status(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI0J0.png) as "Still running".your tag status should be "Succeeded".check this if it is useful https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/tag-manager/LcmS4z7_xC8/B0QbYFmsCAAJ

Comment: Can you click on "show more" for the tag in the debugging console

Comment: I would suggest you check 2 things: 1. is your ga configuration in GTM is correct eg: wrong ga id 2. check if you apply a wrong fiter in your ga view (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en). 
BTW, there is a misconfiguration in your tag, the non-interaction hit should be false. because click is an interaction, but this should not be the cause of missing info in GA

Comment: In response to XTOTHEL, here is the "show more"

http://prntscr.com/li2xh8

Comment: I also had this problem when i had an ad blocker extension running.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that link, Uda! What was going wrong was my Google Optimize Tag. I paused all tags except my click-tracking and my Universal Analytics